# rdflib's parseQuery decode the query string which cause invalid URI

Tags: python, character-encoding, ttl, rdflib

I have the following ttl file:

```
@prefix : <https://www.example.co/reserved/language#> .

<https://www.example.co/reserved/root> :_id "01G39WKRH76BGY5D3SKDHJP2SX" ;
    :transcript%20data [ :_id "01G39WKRH7JYRX78X7FG4RCNYF" ;
            :_key "transcript%20data" ;
            :value "value" ;
            :value_id "01G39WKRH7PVK1DXQHWT08DZA8" ] .
```

And I have the following query:

```py
q = """
PREFIX : <https://www.example.co/reserved/language#>

    SELECT  ?o 
    WHERE { ?s :transcript%20data/:value ?o . }
"""
```

While trying to query the graph I got from the ttl file I got the following error:

```
https://www.example.co/reserved/language#transcript data does not look like a valid URI, trying to serialize this will break.
```

As you see, `parseQuery` has decoded the "%20" to a space " " which cases invalid URI. And this will return `False` while passed to [`_is_valid_uri`](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/blob/ccb9c4a56e6bfcf1474480552e62a21461b85239/rdflib/term.py#L87-L91) function.

I've tested the query on different SPARQL engines and it is valid and works as expected.
So, what do you advise? to make the query valid and get the required results?

*I am using rdflib Version: 6.1.1 on macOS Monterey 12.4*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug in rdflib in SPARQL parser and it is fixed in this [PR](https://github.com/RDFLib/rdflib/pull/1959)

> Seems like _hexExpand internal SPARQL parser function inappropriately expands percent-encoded reserved characters. Added an exclusionary regexp to disable this behaviour and a parameterized test which checks SPARQL parser processing of the set of percent-encoded reserved chars